# Xamarin.forms - MasterDetailPage below status bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've tried achieving this by creating a master detail page renderer and put the following line of code:

SetFitsSystemWindows(true);

in the renderer's constructor. However, the master page's height was cut.

Do you guys have idea on how to fix it other than putting a hardcoded padding value in the master page?

Here's a screenshot how it looks like:

https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/7u/1t5afe5kt3wo.png

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the statusbar and offset it.

```
var statusBarHeight = 0;
var resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier ("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
```

Comment: Hi Adam, what is the complete solution to making the `MasterDetailPage`'s Master not go under the status bar? If I derive from the XF's `MasterDetailPageRenderer` what do I need to call? Thanks!